# Can GetHashCode() for the same double result in a different integer?

Tags: c#, hashcode, gethashcode, hash-code-uniqueness

Is it possible for the `GetHashCode()` method to return different integer values for the same `double` value on different computers, operating systems, or architectures? For example, if I have the following code:

```
    public unsafe override int GetHashCode() {
        double d = m_value; 
        if (d == 0) { 
            // Ensure that 0 and -0 have the same hash code
            return 0; 
        }
        long value = *(long*)(&d);
        return unchecked((int)value) ^ ((int)(value >> 32));
    }
```

Could `hash1` be a different integer on a different computer or operating system than it is on the original computer? Is the behavior of `GetHashCode()` for `double` values consistent across different environments?

Comment: if possible, then what?

Comment: As the result of GetHashCode is implementation-specific, then, in principle, yes, why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Object.GetHashCode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.100).aspx) says:

> The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects. Furthermore, the .NET Framework does not guarantee the default implementation of the GetHashCode method, and the value it returns will be the same between different versions of the .NET Framework. Consequently, the default implementation of this method must not be used as a unique object identifier for hashing purposes.

Comment: While true, this is not relevant to the question, because `double` overrides `GetHashCode` implementation. And even if it did not - `ValueType` overrides `GetHashCode` of object (and double is struct).

Comment: @Evk So still it is possible for double.GetHashCode() to return two different integers on different .Net? I'm confused.

Comment: @Vahid there is no such requirement, so you never can be sure. Full .NET framework may do one thing, .NET core might do another thing, mono might do yet another one. Or they might all do the same thing now, and in next version this can change.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.